# postgresql image deployed with docker fails to authenticate spring applications after running for a while

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, spring-data

i have a micro-services project developed with spring boot/cloud that contains at leas 14 different services and using postgresql docker image as a database.
when deploying to prod env with docker compose everything works like a charm, here is my docker compose:

```
    version: '3.7'
    volumes:
      db-data:
        name: db-data
    services:
      db:
        image: 'postgres:11.5'
        command: postgres -c 'max_connections=200'
        container_name: postgres
        ports:
          - '5432:5432'
        volumes:
          - 'db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
        environment:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
  auth:
    container_name: auth
    image: auth
    environment:
      JAVA_OPTS: '-Xmx500m -XX:+UseSerialGC -Xss512k -XX:MaxRAM=72m'
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: prod
    build:
      context: ./auth
      dockerfile: DockerFile
    ports:
      - '9100:9100'
    depends_on:
      - db
```

and here is my application-prod.yml for a service example:

```
    spring:
      datasource:
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 4
    url: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/postgres?ApplicationName=${spring.application.name}&currentSchema=${app.database.schema-name}
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
  jpa:
    open-in-view: false
    show-sql: true
    hibernate.ddl-auto: create
    generate-ddl: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc:
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true
  output:
    ansi:
      enabled: detect
```

now after 2 or 3 days of deployment the postgres container starts showing this log:
[image]

and all of my services shows this log:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:475) ~[postgresql-42.2.1.jar!/:42.2.1]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:207) ~[postgresql-42.2.1.jar!/:42.2.1]
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) [postgresql-42.2.1.jar!/:42.2.1]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195) [postgresql-42.2.1.jar!/:42.2.1]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:452) [postgresql-42.2.1.jar!/:42.2.1]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:254) [postgresql-42.2.1.jar!/:42.2.1]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117) [HikariCP-2.7.8.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:123) [HikariCP-2.7.8.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:365) [HikariCP-2.7.8.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:194) [HikariCP-2.7.8.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:460) [HikariCP-2.7.8.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$100(HikariPool.java:71) [HikariCP-2.7.8.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:697) [HikariCP-2.7.8.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:683) [HikariCP-2.7.8.jar!/:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

i couldn't figure out why, everything was working perfictly, could anyone help me figure out why is this happening?

Comment: Perhaps someone is logging on with your incredibly easy to guess password, and then changing that password.  Locking you out.

Comment: [@jjanes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1721239/jjanes) i know i sad prod env, but that's actully a pre-prod env, which is for QA ppl to make sure everything is fine, so not a security thing i assure you

Comment: It is hard to see what else might be happening.  It doesn't need to be prod to have a security problem, as long as it is exposed to an untrusted network (or anyone on the trusted network is not really trustworthy).  Is this repeatable or is it a one-time problem?

Comment: This happens every 1-2 days after redeployment, how i fix this is i log into the container and redefine the same old for the same user with ‘psql’ and ‘\password’

Comment: it happen sometime or can not connect at all @Dever

Comment: [@Thanh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4144042/thanh-nguyen-van) after 2-3 days of each full redeployment of all services including postgresql,

Comment: You could set log_statement=ddl (or higher) and see what happened just before it starts failing.  Also, after resetting you could record the password hash from pg_authid or pg_shadow and see it had changed once it starts failing.

Comment: Can I know the complete docker command which you're using to deploy?

Answer (score 1):

Try to define a password for the user Postgres

1. `docker ps`
2. `docker exec -it <container_name> bash`
3. Start the query console `psql`
4. Define pwd `ALTER ROLE postgres WITH PASSWORD 'your_pwd'`

***Container Management:***

UP -- `docker-compose up --remove-orphans --force-recreate --build PostgreSQL`

Comment: [Ashok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11745452/ashok)   Do you have a guess about whats going on?!?

Comment: didn't get you?

Comment: Why is this behavior appears?

Comment: That I'm not sure exactly but when I faced the issue I tried this way and it worked for me

Comment: And it never happened again?

Comment: I encountered this 2 months back and till now I didn't encounter it